# VSCode and ES6 warnings

Tags: jshint, visual-studio-code

I keep on getting ES6 jshint warnings, for example:
''import' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6'). (W119)'
source: 'jshint'
code: 'W119'

I followed suggestions such as

1. Adding a .jshintrc file in the root with 
   {
       "esversion": 6
   }
2. Adding the following to the user and\or workspace settings:
      "jshint.options":{
          "esversion":6
      }

But I still get the warning. Are there other things that I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Add a file .jshintrc into your project root, the warnings will disappear.

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

Answer (score 5):

jsHint's ES6 warning can be solved easily by the following JSON code without creating any new file:
Paste the code inside the JSON editor of the "user settings".

`"jshint.options": { "esversion": 6 },`

Answer (score 1):

[jsconfig.json file which defines the JavaScript target to be ES6](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)

I create a jsconfig.json file under my project directory and add codes in it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
},
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the JSHint documentation: https://jshint.com/docs/ "In addition to using configuration files you can configure JSHint from within your files using special comments. These comments start with a label such as jshint or globals..."

So, a /* jshint esversion: 6 */ comment will work on the top of each file targeting ES6.
This have the advantage of you can switch these directives on and off per file or per function: "These comments are function scoped meaning that if you put them inside a function they will affect only this function's code."